# JQUERY GET error if set header Authorization

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I used

- jquery V3.6.3
- method: GET

if I set header Authorization value, it don't work.

this work

```
$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url:'https://........../test',
          success: function (data){

          },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, request, error){
            
          }
        });
```

this don't work

```
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url:'https://........../test',
          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
          },
          success: function (data){

          },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, request, error){

          }
        });
```

I tried many options, one at time or more at time

```
async: false,
crossDomain: true, 
dataType: "jsonp"
```

Comment: check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/use-basic-authentication-with-jquery-and-ajax

Comment: before create this question, I watched it